# How do I organize stuff in blueocean- views? folders?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Right now my blueocean is just a big list of ALL my projects on the same page, how do I organize them? I'd like to have different tabs or something to break them up by team at least.

I haven't seen any examples of how to do this. In old jenkins there are folders and views for this.

Edit: So this question is specific to the main pipelines page. And it seems like this page is not usable if you have many projects and is perhaps only for smaller teams. It would be nice to have this feature or some clarity from the jenkins folks on this though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is slow, which is why [JENKINS-44867](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44867) is still an issue.

There was tabs before because it facilitated the access to the job definition and the definition of groups of jobs.

With a pipeline approach, this was not needed anymore:

- the job definition is right there in the source of your project (in the Jenkinsfile)
- the definition of group is delegated to your repository hosting server website, like your own GitLab instance, which does allow the definition of [groups (and sub-groups)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group/subgroups/) of projects. (GitHub has [organizations and teams](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/admin/guides/user-management/organizations-and-teams/))

Comment: OK not really my issue. Not the slowness I just want to *organize* stuff in blue ocean. Yes i have teams in my hosting provider but I still need to login to jenkins sometimes and its just a big list of everything when I look at in blue ocean. Whats the point of having a nice UI if my pipelines page is a big mess? Ideally I want to define the group/team in the jenkinsfile itself and have that represented in blueocean somehow.

Comment: @red888 I agree. My answer was not so much about the performance, and more about the reasons why there was no concept of groups.

Comment: is it the jenkins folks position that you shouldn't need to be looking at the pipelines main page? I guess im missing something obvious here. I love blueocean and the visualized pipeline graphics and the test tab, etc- but maybe I'm unclear on what the workflow should be. I guess if pipelines are automated and users get a message, email, slack whatever, that links them back to that specific pipeline's run so they can see the neat graphic and test tab, etc I suppose we wouldn't need to look at the main page at all?

Comment: @red888 I don't know of their main official position on this, I only see how I use it myself (with *lots* of project): I access directly to the job I want and don't use the main pipeline page.

Comment: OK so this is a pretty open ended question, but would you guess _most_ people just do it this way and don't use the main page? Part of Blueocean's goals seems to be ease of use and not for larger enterprise users (with 60 or more repos like me) so I guess this makes sense. The main page looks nice for their little "look how easy it is to get started with jenkins demos". Still a little disappointing though :(

Comment: @red888 I agree, but BlueOcean is still a work in progress, so it might evolve :)